# Will the optimizer prevent the creation of a string parameter if a constant will prevent it from being used?

Tags: java, android, logging, compiler-optimization

My question is best made with an example.

```
  public static boolean DEBUG = false;

  public void debugLog(String tag, String message) {
    if (DEBUG)
      Log.d(tag, message);
  }

  public void randomMethod() {
    debugLog("tag string", "message string"); //Example A

    debugLog("tag string", Integer.toString(1));//Example B

    debugLog("tag string", generateString());//Example C 
  }


  public String generateString() {
    return "this string";
  }
```

My question is, in any of the examples, A, B or C - since the string would not be used ultimately would the optimizer remove it?

Or asked another way, would it be better to do the following, thus ensuring that the string objects would not be created?

```
  public void randomMethod() {
    if (DEBUG) debugLog("tag string", "message string"); //Example A

    if (DEBUG) debugLog("tag string", Integer.toString(1));//Example B

    if (DEBUG) debugLog("tag string", generateString());//Example C 
  }
```

Comment: The optimizer (if written right) should remove them.

Comment: Actually, the strings in A and C are literals and thus interned, so no string is created either way. But that doesn't matter for the question, I get what you mean.

Comment: @JesusRamos Compiler writers would like to have a work with you, about correctness and practicality

Comment: @JesusRamos what about in situation C?  The question if it's a good idea aside, it's possible you might be relying on some processing occurring in the called function?

Comment: @delnan Well if the branch becomes an if (0) the interning the string would be somewhat pointless (although a parse tree still has to be created so it might be more work to clean up if the interning is done during the parsing or not). The code still has to be parsed for correctness of course and in terms of practicality it might just depend. Now that doesn't mean that the strings should be included in the final binary (maybe in some intermediate compilation units).

Comment: @delnan my understanding is that a string literal like that actually creates a string object...so "hello," + "world" would create two objects.  Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the term "interning"?  Ah: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning  So, in other words a singular object would be created, not an object with every call?  Still the question still stands, will the string be created at all?

Comment: @AnthonyTanas: Yes - a reference to the same string object will be returned by every call to `generateString()`. No new string objects are created by either A or C. Only B generates a new string - assuming it's not cached within `Integer.toString()` for some common values. (I don't know offhand whether or not it is.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I got that now, so my question is (let's refer to example A for simplicity) would the string object exist *at all* in the first snippet or not?  And what about the second snippet?  I understand that any way that it does exist, it will be interned and exist once.  I learned something new with that, but my original question is how can I prevent the string from existing at all.  We have a very complex process with hundreds of debug logging statements.  I'm wondering if I should add the conditional as in the second snippet for efficiency at release or not bother?

Comment: @AnthonyTanas: Yes, the string will exist. I doubt that you can prevent that. Aside from anything else, bear in mind that any other code can currently set your `DEBUG` variable to `true`. If it were a *final* variable, the JIT would have more wiggle room. Do you have any evidence that this is actually causing you a problem?

Comment: @JesusRamos The variable may change its value at any time, and the `debugLog` method may be overriden by a subclass. That means *at best* you can *speculatively* remove that code, with a check and fallback to remove the optimization should either assumption. Not even whole-program analysis can save you, as a subclass might be loaded dynamically (e.g. a plugin). Some tracing JIT compilers actually do things like this, but it's *much* more complex than you imagine it to be. For starters, it is about as far removed from the parser as it can be and the interned string *will* be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is not removed for the first snippet, but it is for the second:

```
public class TestCompiler {
    public static boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static void debug(Object o) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println(new InnerClass());
        }
        System.out.println("now nested");
        debug(new InnerClass());
    }
    private static final class InnerClass {
        static {
            System.out.println("Innerclass initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

For me (openjdk7), this results in:

```
now nested
Innerclass initialized
```

meaning that the `if (DEBUG) {...}` is removed, but the method call is not, thus the method parameters are set up.

Comment: It was meant about Android OS, but I think that in this case the result is the same.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. :O
But, you can run that test also, can't you?

Comment: Yes, just instead of the main function, it would be run in an Activity's onCreate() method, or something else.

Comment: I'm not understanding the comments here @androiddeveloper .  Is the response still good?  I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: It's OK. It's just that it's Java style (with main function) , and not Android style (with activities and such). Of course, you are the one who asked the question, so you have to decide if it's good enough.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying.  It's not important that it is strictly Android code so long as the idea is the same.  So essentially the second snippet from the main question should lead to more optimized release code when DEBUG is false.  That is the essence of what I wanted to know so yes, I think this is fine.  Thanks to all! :-)